# Amazon forest in Colombia

Tags: adventure, south-america, colombia, amazon-jungle, amazon-river

I will be in Colombia for the first 2 weeks in March and want to visit the Amazon rain forest for sure. I want to take out 3-4 days for it. I will be in Bogota and will probably choose a flight to spend more time in the forest.
What are the places, adventures or any kind of experience that one should go for. Please include some sort of priority/ labels with approximate time required for them that can help me and others to plan better. I would appreciate related suggestions, links and remarks as well.

Comment: i havent seen but i think there are two - one by Brazilian and other by Colombian. why does it matter though?

Comment: because i just watched it and they show how they used the rain forest as a cover to build coke labs..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis you mean Narcos ?

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis I have seen few documentaries in past which suggested the same - "using forest as a cover". Have you been there though?

Comment: @singhsumit not yet, it is on the top of my bucket list.

Comment: @blackbird57 yes Narcos, I can't wait for season 2..

Answer (score 3):

I was in Leticia, Colombia several years ago and they offered amazon tours. If you do a quick google you will find a couple of companies that offer tours there. The following site is in Spanish, but it will give you some information on their tours:

http://www.amazonascolombia.com/

The tour that I did took us out on the Amazon river. We ate lunch explored some local native villages. It was quite fun.

Also, Leticia has a zoo and many other things you might find interesting to do there. The people were very friendly and helped when it was needed. Leticia is also on the border to Tabatinga, Brasil so you can visit there also if you like.

A flight from Bogotá to Leticia is only a little more than 2 hours.